# Code doesn't work as intended in visual c++ (examples from bjarne stroustrup programming and principles book 2n version)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++17

Okey as I've recently started to read about C++ and try to go with the book I'm having Programming Principles and practice Using C++ 2nd version.

I'm a total newbie so this is probably why, but here goes.

Okey so in the book they have you implement a header .h file instead of the (iostream) etc. So it just have all those for the start as the book doesn't want us to focus on those libraries in the start of the learning.
So i implemented it and used it (not sure if this is related to the problem). Anyway at page 77, I'm getting stuck.

Basically it's a wrong value that's getting entered and it's supposed to just show -1(or 0) as the int gets a false value, etc Carlos(letters, not an integer) so the int doesn't get a correct value so the code that is supposed to work (and show 0 or -1 as it's an incorrect value that's entered) is this according to the book:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
string first_name = "???"; // string variable // ("???” means “don’t know the name”)
int age = –1; // integer variable (–1 means “don’t know the age”)
cin >> first_name >> age; // read a string followed by an integer
cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

and this is what i wrote:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your first name and age" << endl;
string First_Name = "???";
int Age = -1;
cin >> First_Name >> Age;
cout << "Hello, " << First_Name << "(age" << Age << ")" << endl;
keep_window_open();
return 0;
}
```

However, the result with visual c++ for me is a crash when i for example write 22 Carlos.
According to the book it's supposed to output Hello, 22 (age -1)

But for me it just crashes after i enter the word Carlos as value for age...
I don't get a a error or anything when i run and compile it, but it crashes after when i give the false value for age.

What am i doing wrong?
add: I know i can use a string to get it to work, however I'm just interested in why it doesn't work as I'm following this book i wish to follow it without having these kind of problems as it's intended to work.

Here is a gif when im doing it:
[http://imgur.com/a/ERjhz](https://imgur.com/a/ERjhz)
Solution: To use system("pause"); instead of keep_window_open(); 
however it's still annoying to read the book with the knowledge that the code in the book doesn't work always :(

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using, it works as intended in MSVC2015.

Comment: Could you try including `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` instead of the include you added? Just to see if it works that way.

Comment: The book is sightly out of date.  According to the current standard, the correct output has 0, not -1. However the program should not crash.  Are you sure the program compiles? It contains a non-standard minus sign that is not legal in C++ programs. They ifteb appear when MS Word or other word processor is used for entering the program. Don't do that. Use a programmer's text editor.

Comment: I'm using Visual studio community 2017 edition to write my code in.By the way i tried to include the iostream and string however it didn't work either (yes i removed the keep_window_open(); as it's referencing to the one i used before)

Comment: Apologies, the first sample contains an invalid character, the second one doesn't.

Comment: I've tried to use 0 as well, still doesn't work. I added a picture where i run it.

Comment: I don't think your program really crashes. Try tracing it step by step in the debugger. The apparent problem may have to do with a bad definition of keep_window_open. Can you post it? A naïve implementation of this function will break if `cin` has encountered a formatting error.

Comment: @n.m.I've tried to remove the keep_window_open as a Ipares12(user) wanted me to try iostream and string instead of std_lib_facilities.h, yet it crashes.

Comment: Does it "crash" when you remove keep_window_open and use **correct** input?

Comment: It doesn't crash if i do what I'm supposed to do (Name -> number) It works as well if i do Number -> number but not when the Name/number -> name. So whenever i use letters for the int it crashes (but it's supposed to do/show the null value -1 or 0). I removed the keep_window_open and removed the std_lib~.h when i did it and it still just closes. Maybe it's not a crash but it just closes.

Comment: Please explain precisely what happens in both cases (name/number and number/name) **when you remove keep_window_open**. Please don't use words like "crash", relate exactly what you are doing and what you are seeing, nothing more (for example: "I press the enter key", "a window opens", "a window closes", "output that reads '...' appears").

Comment: Okey so for the code i wrote earlier in the op as my code. I run it, enter a Name -> presses enter -> new line typing "carlos" -> presses enter -> console closes. It works as intended if i do what it's supposed to do which is following: Runs -> Types Name - > presses enter -> Types 5 -> presses enter -> output shows "Hello Name (age5) -> presses a key and presses enter to get the console closed.

Comment: Please describe what happens **with the program with keep_window_open renoved**. Remove keep_window_open and try running your program. Explain what happens. Did I mention that you should remove keep_window_open?

Comment: Yes, the same thing is happening as i described above when i remove the keep_window_open. However i found a solution. Instead of using the keep_window_open(); is used system("pause"); and it works! The big question is if i have to use system("pause"); instead of keep_window_open(); over the entire practicies i do with the book now.

Comment: Could you please explain how come you **presses a key and presses enter to get the console closed** works **without keep_window_open**? Is it by magic? Because this can only happen by magic. There's nothing in your program except keep_window_open that would make it behave like you have described, and you have removed keep_window_open.

Comment: Replacing keep_window_open with system("pause") fixes the problem. This could have to do with the fact that the problem is in keep_window_open, as I have said in the beginning. Well, learning the hard way is an invaluable experience I guess.

Comment: You are correct, when i removed the keep_window_open it closes after i have entered the number. However it doesn't explain why it makes it close when i have it (only when i make a letter when im supposed to write a number). So the code simply doesn't work as the book lays out. I had to find the system("pause"); instead to get it to work. Question, should i use the book even if it causes problem like these?

Comment: Most of the code works. Only keep_window_open doesn't work, and that's only when you don't enter correct data. It's a simple error that doesn't reflect the overall book quality. You may replace keep_window_open with system("pause") or try to fix it. I have asked you to post its implementation but you never did.

Comment: I have looked at the code of `keep_window_open` as posted by Stroustrup on the site of the book http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/std_lib_facilities.h It should work as advertised. Are you sure your version corresponds to what is posted there?

Comment: Yep, i double checked it. Copied it over to a txt document and copied the text from the link you gave me and renamed it to std_lib_facilities.h which converted it to a c/c++ header file and copied over to Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include folder and re-tried to use the keep_window_open(); which results as it did before. It works all as intended except when i enter a letter instead of a number on the last command. It just closes after i have pressed a letter to the console and presses enter (i can type the name as regular

Comment: and i can type the number as regular but if i type name -> name it closes) If i do as it's intended (Name -> number) it shows the output which is Hello name (age number) then i press a letter and presses enter to get it to close.

Comment: Sorry, I have checked again and it indeed doesn't work. It's a tricky function that is hard to get right.

Comment: I have emailed Mr Stroustrup a link to this thread.

Comment: :o really? I would never think it was worth the time, thought it just was a fault on my part somehow. Oh well, glad i could point out if it's needed to be fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is isn't  a problem but too fast to be noticed by our eyes.

i am adding the function definition of keep_window_open()

```
inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    return;
}
```

As you can see it simply takes the character input from the us
Forward you will learn about input stream and its buffer
So when you input a character in place of integer there is error flagged in the stream(background) and the only one of the characters input is used(in your case 'C' is used for flagging).

I am using input as Carlos 22

So now the input stream is still having characters 'a','r','l','o','s',22
so now the **'a'** is used as a input for **keep_window_open** function
and the program ends without waiting for a input from you
So there is no error or crash but since the character is already there for input for keep_window_open function so its kind of really fast

Comment: Also for the error flagged the function cin.clear clears out any error flags raised and restores the stream back to normal

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `keep_window_open`. It's a tricky function that is very hard to get absolutely right. You can replace it with this code that sidesteps the problem but only works on Windows:

```
inline void keep_window_open()
{
   system("pause");
}
```

or with this slightly more complicated code that tries to take more cases into account:

```
inline void keep_window_open()
{
    cout << "Please enter a character to exit\n";
    if (!cin)
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(120, '\n');
    }
    char ch;
    cin >> skipws >> ch;
}
```

(This assumes you don't enter lines longer than 120 characters. Replace 120 with `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` if you want it to be free from arbitrary limits. Other functions from std_lib_facilities.h do use 120 in this situation. You many or may not have to add `#include <limits>` directive to your program).

I have tested in a couple of cases and it appears to work with both correct and incorrect input to the program, but use it at your own risk. It still may or may not work correctly if your program requires more complicated input.

Answer (score -1):

A good rule is to always except that the end users is idiots, so you need to write the program in a way that can handles all kinds of inputs without crashing. Therefore always read input numbers as `std::string` and then try convert it to `int`, `short`, `double`, `unsigned int` or what ever datatype you are using.

Your code should look like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int age;
    std::string first_name;
    std::string input_age;

    std::cout << "Please enter your first name and age: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> first_name >> input_age; // Read the age as 'std::string'

    try
    {
            age = std::stoi(input_age); // Try to convert age from 'std::string' to 'int'
            std::cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (" << age << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::invalid_argument& ex) // 'std::stoi()' will throw 'std::invalid_argument' if it's not able to convert 'std::string' to 'int'
    {
            std::cerr << "Unable to convert input value ('" << input_age << "') to 'int'" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Debug info: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(std::out_of_range& ex) // 'std::stoi()' will throw 'std::out_of_range' if 'std::string' is too small or too big to store in a 'int'
    {
            std::cerr << "The input value (" << input_age << ") is out of range, please input a value inside the range" << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Debug info: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The question is not about writing correct code. The question is **why code from Stroustrup's book doesn't behave as advertised**. Modifying that code doesn't help you answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but as @n.m Over all the code you gave is a bit to high for me as a newbie to programming :) stoi,cerr,argc etc... things yet to learn :)

Answer (score -4):

**So it's nothing to do with code, it's something to do with input.**

> when i for example write 22 Carlos.

The problem is that the code is asking for `First_Name` then `Age`, Not `Age` then `First_Name`. So when you put **22 for First_Name**, the .exe got confused.

for example lets say I did this

```
int y = 0;
cout << "Give me INT: ";
cin >> y;
cout >> "You put: " >> y;
```

And when I run the program and put this for input

```
Give me INT: ghaisewofasd
*crashed*
```

This is a problem because the user is giving a string for when the code is asking for a int.

So for your case, instead of writing **22 Carlos**, just write **Carlos 22**.
Also keep in mind, this book maybe not so correct, because it shouldn't print out **Hello, (22)**. Now a days stuff like that crash if that happens, maybe it was a older version of C++.

Comment: It's not this. His program crashes when it should be doing `Hello, 22 (age -1)`. Just tried it in Unix and it does have the output he is saying.

Comment: No, if you try to extract `int` from a stream containing non-int characters, value is left unmodified and failbit is set. No crash

Comment: OP **wants** to enter wrong data. The program shouldn't crash.

Comment: Oh I just tested my code in visual c++, it didn't crash. darn I was so like "Man time to get up to 15 points on stack overflow with some questions" and it appears I was wrong. Although I sometimes crash to problems like these

Comment: yea execpt i didnt use ur header and i got -1